# Issue with 802.1q VLAN on VMs in bridge mode with Wi-Fi interface

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, bridge, vlan

My environment is a router with OpenWRT, a laptop connected to the router via patch cable and an untagged VLAN with VID 5 configured on that port in the router, and a MacBook M1 Pro connected via Wi-Fi to the router.

On the MacBook, I created a VLAN interface by specifying en0 (AirPort) as the parent interface, then created a VM using QEMU with hvf accelerator or lima/UTM with VZ and I observe a strange situation: using arping, packets from the laptop sometimes reach the VM connected to the VLAN interface on the macbook, but arping running on the VM only sends requests but does not receive replies from the laptop. If I assign an IP address to the VLAN interface in macOS, packets are transmitted over either protocol without any problems. The problem is delivering packets to the virtual machine.

With tcpdump on the laptop I can see that it reply to arp requests, I can also see on the router that replies to arp requests passed through the Wi-Fi interface, but I don't see them in tcpdump on en0 on the macbook, which is also strange. But as I wrote before, if I assign an address from the same network on the macbook's VLAN interface, any packets are delivered between the laptop and macbook.

- Laptop: 192.168.24.50
- MacBook: 192.168.24.20 (vlan5 interface).
- VM: 192.168.24.10

With lima-vm I use [socket_vmnet](https://github.com/lima-vm/socket_vmnet) in bridge mode. With QEMU I use [vmnet-bridged](https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/interop/qemu-qmp-ref.html#qapidoc-1461).

```
➜  ~ ifconfig vlan5
vlan5: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1496
    options=6063<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether f0:2f:4b:xx:xx:xx
    inet 192.168.24.20 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.24.255
    vlan: 5 parent interface: en0
    media: autoselect
    status: active

➜  ~ ping 192.168.24.50 -c2
PING 192.168.24.50 (192.168.24.50): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.24.50: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.241 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.24.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.429 ms

--- 192.168.24.50 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 5.241/5.335/5.429/0.094 ms

➜  ~ sudo arping -c 5 -i vlan5 192.168.24.50
ARPING 192.168.24.50
60 bytes from 10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx (192.168.24.50): index=0 time=6.061 msec
60 bytes from 10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx (192.168.24.50): index=1 time=6.084 msec
60 bytes from 10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx (192.168.24.50): index=2 time=5.945 msec
60 bytes from 10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx (192.168.24.50): index=3 time=3.092 msec
60 bytes from 10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx (192.168.24.50): index=4 time=3.848 msec

--- 192.168.24.50 statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received,   0% unanswered (0 extra)
rtt min/avg/max/std-dev = 3.092/5.006/6.084/1.278 ms

➜  ~ ifconfig bridge100
bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1496
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    ether f2:2f:4b:xx:xx:xx
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: vlan5 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 22 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: vmenet0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 23 priority 0 path cost 0
    Address cache:
        10:e7:c6:xx:xx:xx Vlan1 vlan5 326 flags=0<>
        52:55:55:ae:36:b4 Vlan1 vmenet0 1172 flags=0<>
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

```
[root@VM1 ~]# arping 192.168.24.50 -c5
ARPING 192.168.24.50 from 192.168.24.10 lima0
Sent 5 probes (5 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
[root@VM1 ~]#
```

```
[root@laptop ~]# arping 192.168.24.10 -c5
ARPING 192.168.24.10 from 192.168.24.50 eth0
Unicast reply from 192.168.24.10 [52:55:55:AE:36:B4] 2.492ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.24.10 [52:55:55:AE:36:B4] 1.791ms
Unicast reply from 192.168.24.10 [52:55:55:AE:36:B4] 3.059ms
Sent 5 probes (1 broadcast(s))
Received 3 response(s)
[root@laptop ~]#
```

I also did a test on the laptop, in VirtualBox I created the VM with the interface in bridge mode and inside the VM I created a VLAN interface. I switched the laptop to Wi-Fi and tried pinging the MacBook's VM. Packets are leaving the laptop VM, but not coming to the MacBook VM.

So it's not OS dependent, the issue is that packets are not being sent to the VM itself when it's connected to the Wi-Fi interface.

I would like to figure this out. It's not really transparent to me. The VLAN header is only 4 bytes, so **what's the problem with passing that frame between the VM interface and the Wi-Fi interface in bridge mode?** However, if you assign an IP address in the OS to a VLAN interface and it has a Wi-Fi interface as its parent interface, everything will work fine.

UPD: thanks for A.B.'s comments, they helped me understand what was preventing the VM from receiving packets.

Comment: I'm not sure how VLAN interacts with this, but if the MacOS is a client, not the AP (OpenWRT) you can't bridge traffic, because of the way Wifi is implemented everywhere: 3 addresses, but bridging on client requires 4 address mode everywhere. 4 addresses? But Ethernet has only 2? Wifi has 4 but usually uses only 3: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25102 . See also this UL SE Q/A (where I made an answer): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/555676/251756 So: can you configure both OpenWRT and MacOS to 4A mode? requires hardware, firmware, driver and OS support (+ conf tools support).

Comment: Some hypervisors (possibly virtualbox) have tricks to handle the MAC address and do a sort of MAC NAT. That's similar to Linux' IPVLAN in my link. But they would also have to handle this in a VLAN tagged frames context. I doubt that's available. site appears down. https://web.archive.org/web/20231124220645/www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged . (note "because most wireless adapters do not support promiscuous mode" is just crap to avoid a complex explanation from them). Consider "802.1q" an other protocol so without support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I described issue in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/amkgi/78c3b6256b400fcdea856518eaa0460e).

For this to work, MAC NAT is needed. To add MAC NAT, run the command - `sudo ifconfig bridge10X macnat vlanX`

The MACNAT flag is set [automatically](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu/blob/1031c584a5e37aff177559b9f69dbd3c8c3fd30a/bsd/net/if_bridge.c#L2754C1-L2754C4) in the case of a bridge connection to a wireless interface:

```
    if (wifi_infra) {
        (void)bridge_mac_nat_enable(sc, bif);
    }
```

So I haven't encountered this issue before until I needed the VLANs.